# Duplicate home page URL in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics under Behaviour > Overview we're seeing some URL's which go to our home page, but are not internal links within our site.

I've redacted the domain name but our home page is set up at `www.domain.com` and `/` is shown in Analytics which we recognise as the home page.

Now we're seeing some URL's such as:

`/?success=5`

These open our home page, because the route is still `/` with the 'success' GET parameter.

How can we find out where these are coming from, and is there any way to tell Analytics to "group" all such URL's so they are treated as the home page.

As I say, we ourselves have not implemented anything on-site to suggest a URL such as `/?success=5` is a valid URL; so I assume they are coming from somewhere externally but do not know where.

I've read about doing redirects but that seems a very poor solution as we have no way of determining where these URL's are originating from and maintaining a big list of redirects could be a big job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove query strings from incoming hits either

- in the view settings (if you have a finite list of parameter names you want to remove); enter the names into the "exlude query parameters" textbox as comma separated list
- via view filters (if you need to remove multiple query strings, or all query strings)

[Lunametrics has an article that explains the various possible filter settings](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/04/17/strip-query-parameters-google-analytics/).

You should keep an unfiltered view as backup, though; filter change data in a view permanently and there is no way to recover data that has accidentally been filtered out.

There is not much you can do for urls that has already been collected.